# How to extract default styles from a MUI Component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I retrieve the default styles of a specific component, such as the minWidth of a button? For instance, if I have an interface where users can adjust the width of a Button, I need to provide an initial value for the input field so users know the default value for that property.

I attempted to look through the node_modules directory, but I couldn't find any CSS files there.

Comment: Providing your own default values would probably make more sense, but MUI does have [a page for exploring their default theme](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/default-theme/) if you really want to dig into it.

Comment: @DBS If I choose to set my own default values, the components may not match MUI components exactly. Additionally, the default theme page only offers global styles, lacking styles tailored to specific components.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a default `minWidth` first, and then change the value of `width` dynamically using the user input obtained from a `TextField`. Check out the following example:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Button, TextField, Stack} from '@mui/material';

export default function BasicButtons() {
  const [buttonWidth, setButtonWidth] = React.useState<number>(50);
  const onChange = (event) => {
    setButtonWidth(event.target.value)
  }
  return (
    <Stack spacing={2} direction="row">
      <TextField value={buttonWidth} onChange={onChange} id="standard-basic" label="Standard" variant="standard" />
      <Button variant="outlined" sx={{minWidth: '100px', width: buttonWidth + "px"}}>Outlined</Button>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

You can run the example above using this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vmftbd?file=Demo.tsx).

And to check the default style values of MUI components, the easiest way is to render a component first and then inspect the DOM elements individually via browser's `Inspector` panel.